# JPA @Id @GeneratedValue annotations vs DB primary key?

Tags: jpa, annotations

I have an app accessing an existing MySQL DB utilizing JDBC and am converting to JPA.  My DB is already setup with primary keys which are auto generated.  Do I need to annotate my entity classes w/ @Id, @GeneratedValue... when this is already defined in the DB?  Will the annotations override / conflict with the DB primary key / indexes already defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using autonumbers in MySQL and these are autogenerated.

The following code will do what you require:

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Basic(optional = false)
@Column(name = "table_id")
```

Notice the `GenerationType.IDENTITY` strategy? This tells JPA to use the autogenerated database values.

Comment: I do use the GenerationType.IDENTITY strategy.  I already have the DB created w/ an Object ID primary key w/ auto_increment.  Just wanted to make sure that the MySQL auto_incremement and JPA @GeneratedValue wouldn't conflict.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

It not going to conflict with the DB primary key and the JPA annotations.Since primary key is already indexed, it's not a problem at all.

You should add annotations in entity classes.It is not going to conflict with already defined DB.If you deploy the system in new DB environment then annotations must be needed.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!  I assumed this to be the case but good to get confirmation.